# Reach and Social Reach are zero when we specify date criteria

Tags: api, ads, facebook-ads-api

We try to get the unique stats on Facebook Ads API and we've some difficult to get. Currently, we can only pull the reach (unique_impressions) and the social reach (social_unique_impressions) for one day otherwise when we specify date criteria these fields are returned as zero. We know that unique stats aren't meant to be aggregated. How to retrieve these values? how do you calculate?

Answer (score 1):

Ok! I got a response from Facebook team, it isn't possible to get the unique stats via our own date criteria. It's limit!

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of Facebook's data and is specifically mentioned in the [Ad Statistics Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adstatistics/) - the unique stats are only calculated on Facebook's side in 1, 7 or 28 day ranges:

> Querying Unique Stats
>
> Unique stats are available for time ranges of 1,
>   7 or 28 days exactly.